# Data share between two task in airflow dag

Tags: airflow

I want to do hive query using HiveOperator and the output of that query should transfer to python script using PythonOperator. Is it possible and how?

Comment: a good way is to write the output to s3 or something and then pass the link to the next task via xcoms

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this kind of problem in general is to use Airflow's xcoms - see [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms)

However, I would use this sparingly and only where strictly necessary. Otherwise, you risk ending up with your operators being quite tangled and interdependent.

Comment: thanks PirateNinjas. But using xcom how do i push that query result to another task. Do you have any example code?

Comment: @RohanK i believe the commands are xcom_push() and xcom_pull(). You will have to look these up in the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom